# How to configure the Maven dependency for Guice 3.0 for use without AOP?

Tags: java, android, maven, maven-3, guice

I have an Android Maven project and want to use [Google Guice 3.0](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Guice30) in it.

There is a "No-AOP" version of Guice, which is compatible with Android.

How can I tell [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) to use the "No-AOP" version of [guice](/questions/tagged/guice)?

**Update 1 (03.05.2013 10:46 MSK):**

When I add the dependency on Google Guice, I get following exception during the build (`mvn clean install`):

```
[INFO] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/inject/Abs
tractModule;
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:12
3)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpen
er.java:245)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.j
ava:131)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java
:109)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
[INFO]  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
[INFO] 1 error; aborting
```

Here are my dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <classifier>no_aop</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Make sure this (robolectric dependency) is below the android dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-RC4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.achartengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>achartengine</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0M8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.altruix</groupId>
        <artifactId>ccp-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.altruix</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify `no_aop` as classifier like this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
   <version>3.0</version>
   <classifier>no_aop</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9173321/1343161) can help you resolve the new error?

Comment: It is likely that something else is pulling in a non-no_aop Guice dependency.  Use `mvn dependency:tree` to find out.

Answer (score 2):

If you also want to get rid of the aopalliance dependency, use this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <classifier>no_aop</classifier>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google **discourages** Guice usage on Android because of reflection performance. The last **no_aop** version you can use is:

```
compile 'com.google.inject:guice:2.0-no_aop'
```

---

`'com.google.inject:guice:3.0-no_aop'` is no longer in the maven repository, as well as `'com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0-no_aop'`.

---

`'com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0` crashes on Android with:
`com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

and

```
compile ('com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0') {
   exclude group: 'aopalliance', module: 'aopalliance'
}
```

crashes with `NoClassDefFoundError: org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor`