# Eclipse - unable to install breakpoints on inner class

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven, guice

I am trying to debug a Java program that contains a fair number of anonymous inner classes.
Whenever I start the program in Eclipse's debug mode, I get the following messages:

```
Unable to install breakpoint in my.own.code.SomeClass1$$FastClassByGuice$$21bac442
Unable to install breakpoint in my.own.code.SomeClass2$$FastClassByGuice$$7880adb3
Unable to install breakpoint in my.own.code.SomeClass2$$FastClassByGuice$$7880adb3
Unable to install breakpoint in my.own.code.SomeClass3$$FastClassByGuice$$9ac6f2a1
Unable to install breakpoint in my.own.code.SomeClass4$$FastClassByGuice$$8ae07d4b
Unable to install breakpoint in my.own.code.SomeClass4$$FastClassByGuice$$9ac6f2a1
Unable to install breakpoint in my.own.code.SomeClass5$$FastClassByGuice$$2ef92190
Unable to install breakpoint in my.own.code.SomeClass6$$FastClassByGuice$$c98d2633
```

For each breakpoint in one of my anonymous inner classes I get a message like those above.
**How do I fix that? I need to debug my anonymous inner classes.**

Some extra info: My program consists of 4 maven modules inside one large maven project.
I compile them all in the same way using Oracle's jdk1.7.
Just to be sure, I added the following to all my modules' `pom.xml`s, but without any luck:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <debug>true</debug>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I have also looked at ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760856/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes), [3](http://www.ericparshall.com/2012/01/unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to.html)), but my eclipse settings are okay.

Comment: Sometimes its just plain class issue can you delete bin folder and see again

Comment: I get this error but my breakpoints work anyway, so I just ignore them. Are you sure your breakpoints don't work?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure my breakpoints *don't* work. This is the weird part, since the rest of the internet seems to report that the error messages don't affect the eventual debugging.

Comment: I've hit a similar issue and judging by the error message, the issue is actually caused by Guice - which likely uses some bytecode manipulation library internally.  As reported by others, my breakpoints are being hit nonetheless...

Answer (score 2):

Guice uses bytecode generation for [AOP](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP) (Aspect Oriented Programming), faster reflection, and to proxy circular dependencies.

Since version 2.0 of Guice, [AOP is optional](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/OptionalAOP). For example you can use `2.0-no_aop`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-no_aop</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have no idea how you can use no AOP with version 3.0

Comment: Jmini, I think this answer might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352798/how-to-configure-the-maven-dependency-for-guice-3-0-for-use-without-aop